# Partition generated by a class of subsets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a set and $\mathscr{A}$ a class of subsets of $\Omega$ 
 ($\mathscr{A}=\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ ). Then an equivalent relation is defined by:

$$a \sim b \quad iff \quad \forall A \in \mathscr{A} \quad ( a \in A \, and \, b\in A ) \, or \, (a \in A^c \, and \, b \in A^c)$$

This relation generates a partition of $\Omega$ which intuitively is the one of all the smallest pieces we can create by intersecting sets in $\mathscr{A}$ or their complementaries.

My question is:

> How could this partition be characterised in a "simple" way in terms of unions and intersections of the sets in $\mathscr{A}$?

My attempt:

We could define auxiliary classes intersecting those subsets by steps:

$$\mathscr{C}_1=\{A \cap B \, : \, A,B \in \mathscr{A}\cup \mathscr{A}^c\}$$

$$\mathscr{C}_i=\{A \cap B \, : \, A,B \in \mathscr{C}_{i-1}\} \quad for 
 \quad i=2,3,...$$

I guess the desired partition is the "limit" of these classes, but I don´t know in which sense and if this is true (mostly in non-countable cases). Moreover I think it should be an easier way of characterising this.

Note:
This question arose reading Section 4 (Subfields part) of "Probability and Measure" of P.Billingsley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let ${\scr B}\subset \scr{A}$, and
$$X_{\scr B} = \bigcap_\limits{A\in\scr{B}} A \cap \bigcap_\limits{A\in\scr{A}\setminus\scr{B}} A^c \subset \Omega$$
It seems to me that every such $X_{\scr B}$ is a member of your partition if and only if it is non empty, and that every set in the partition can be written this way (in a unique way).