# Name for set of sets $\bigcap_{i=1}^k A_i$ where $A_i$ is either $E_i$ or its complement

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, terminology

Suppose there are events $E_i$ for integer values such that $1\leq i\leq k$.  Now let some set of sets (call it $G$) be composed of every set that is the intersection of all $k$ events or (exclusive or) their complements.  I'm finding it difficult to word this correctly, so this should hopefully help:

For example, if $k=2$, then $G$ should ONLY contain:

${E_1 \cap E_2}$,

${E_1 \cap E_2^{'}}$,

${E_1^{'} \cap E_2}$,

${E_1^{'} \cap E_2^{'}}$

Where the apostrophe denotes the event's complement.  **Is there a name for such a set $G$?**

Answer (score 1):

We could call it the **[partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) generated by the class** $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^k$.

Some examples of this usage:

- Dorian Feldman and Martin Fox, *Probability: The Mathematics of Uncertainty*, [Section 4.B: Partition Generated by a Class](https://books.google.com/books?id=c8aAK_UIJBoC&lpg=PA20&ots=8JUUw-7Evx&dq=%22partition%20generated%20by%22&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q=%22partition%20generated%20by%22&f=false)
- Paul Pfeiffer, *Concepts of Probability Theory*, [Definition 2-7b](https://books.google.com/books?id=jdtQAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA71&ots=9_aZvyYOLU&dq=%22partition%20generated%20by%22&pg=PA70#v=onepage&q=%22partition%20generated%20by%22&f=false)
- Achim Klenke, *Probability Theory*, proof of Hahn's decomposition theorem:

  > Define $A_n^0 := A_n$, $A_n^1 := A \setminus A_n$, and let $$\mathcal P_n := \left\{ \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i^{s(i)} : s \in \{0,1\}^n\right\}$$ be the partition of $A$ that is generated by $A_1, \dotsc, A_n$.
- Math.SE: [Partition generated by a class of subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2471746)

Answer (score 0):

The collection G of sets is closed under intersections and complements.

Comment: Is that entirely correct, though?  For example, it doesn't contain $E_1 \cap E_1^{'}$
Also, suppose my k was larger, such as 3.  Then $G$ would contain $E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3$ but not $E_1 \cap E_2$.

Comment: @JohnTravolski It does contain $E_1 \cap E_1'$ - see my answer. Either that or you have to rephrase more carefully what your system is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that your system is closed under complementation since for a given $E$ in your system, $E' = E' \cap E'$ is also in your system.

Since your system is closed under complementation and finite intersection, it's also closed under finite union. Why? Let $E,F$ be in your system. Then
$$
E \cup F = (E' \cap F')'
$$
is in your system as well.

Unless your system is empty, it contains the emptyset (since it is closed under complementation and intersection) and thus is also contains $A$. This sort of system is known as an algebra and well studied in mathematics. (Compare to [$\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra) but we don't require algebras to be closed under countable unions or intersections.)
.